# Seek better sentence to describe that I worked with a team most of whom had PhDs

Tags: sentence-construction

As title, I am trying to write a self-motivation letter, but I think one of the sentences in there is not good enough, but I am not sure how to make it better. The original sentence is

> It was a challenging and exciting opportunity to collaborate with a
>   team almost consisting of PhDs when I just graduated from university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everyone on the team had a PhD except you, you would say

> It was a challenging and exciting opportunity to collaborate with a team consisting entirely of members with PhDs when I had just graduated from university.

"Members with PhDs" is more formal than referring to a person as a "PhD." "Had graduated," the past perfect tense, is appropriate because when you collaborated with the team, your graduation had already occurred.

If almost everyone on the team you joined had a PhD, you would insert "almost" before "entirely."